# Instal 3rd party applications on surface 2 rt 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, arm, windows-rt

Does anyone know if there is a valid script yet to unlock windows 8.1 RT? To install applications recompiled for ARM, Or will there be one for the possible update to windows 10 RT (even though Microsoft says it won't be the full win10 OS just a update)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Microsoft fixed the issue that allowed the jailbreak in Windows RT (6.2.9200) in Windows RT 8.1 (6.3.9600), so you [can no longer compile desktop apps in ARM and run them](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2663906).